# Why was my flag declined here?

Tags: support, flagging, moderation, declined-flags

Under the following question,

[Why does world start to fall apart and burn because of one's tapasya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38398/why-does-world-start-to-fall-apart-and-burn-because-of-ones-tapasya)

there was a comment where one user said something like "those are just metaphors". To this another user replied by bringing in completely unrelated stuffs like darwin's theory of evolution to initiate an argument. Needless to say, the second comment was completely irrelevant to the topic and was provocative in nature.

I flagged it using a custom reason "  irrelevant comment, just to try provoke the other user and draw him into an unnecessary debate. – Rickross 9 hours ago   **declined** "

Why was my flagged declined? Was it declined by mistake (it has happened with me  in the past)? BTW, both the comments are now deleted and the 2nd comment (the one I flagged) deserved more than 100% to be deleted.That's why I was surprised when I found the flag declined.

Comment: Yes, the flag was dismissed before deletion of comment by mistake. Otherwise deletion of comment makes the comment flag helpful.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā please post this as answer. We don't want to have zombie meta posts now :)

Comment: Ok so you can post an answer. @Paṇḍyā

Comment: BTW @Paṇḍyā initially I had chosen the post title to be "Why was my flag declined?" but I was not allowed to post with that title. Because there is a post already with that title. That's why I had to alter it slightly to its current state. So, even if the bodies are different it won't allow me to post two Qs with exactly the same title?

Comment: @Rickross, so you think that *'they're just metaphors'* is a valid comment, but a reply to that comment is 'provoking'? hmm..

Comment: I think you had better ways of replying to that comment if at all replying was needed. If you think that it was unneeded then just flagging it was. the better option @ram

Comment: @Rickross, SK is a known repeat offender, it's like the 4th time he got banned and re-entered here. No need for us to fight over some troll..

Comment: @ram If you find something problematic (rude or offensive) then just flag it, don't start or get involved in [unfriendly](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct) speech.

Comment: @Pandya, will you be removing the mythology tag ?